# TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 46 ocassionally showing

Tags: php, laravel-5

I already set the token in the form:

```
<form action="{{ route('user.store') }}" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{!! csrf_token() !!}">
        <legend>Agregar nuevo usuario.</legend>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>C&oacute;digo empresa</label>
                <input type="number" class="form-control input-sm" name="enterprise" id="enterprise">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Nombre</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="name" id="name">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Email</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control input-sm" name="email" id="email">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Usuario</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="username" id="username">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Password</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control input-sm" name="password" id="password">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="checkbox-inline">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="create_content" id="create_content"> Crea contenido
                </label>
                <label class="checkbox-inline">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="active" id="active"> Activo
                </label>
            </div>

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" id="btn_Crear">Create</button>
        </form>
```

Occasionally I'm receiving the TokenmismathException, and I'm not able to post anymore, If I comment out the line `//'App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken',` in the Kernel.php file and try to post, it works, And if I uncomment the same line again `'App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken',`, now I don't receive the TokenmismatchException, until it stops working.
I'm not using ajax
Does anyone know why this is happening.

Comment: can you please see if your session driver configured properply or there aren't any permissions issues?

Comment: well the driver is the default one, but I have figured it out that the error is because of the session, in the `config/session.php`, `lifetime = 120` and `expire_on_close = false` however the session is not lasting 120 minutes and if the browser is closed the session expires. any clue about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had the exact same problem and never found a good solution. We did find a workaround although.

In your .env file, set the Session storage to Redis (yap, you have to install Redis on your server than). This worked for us, never encountered the same problem again.

Note, this works for us, but it of course is not a solution, merely a work-around until someone found the right solution.